# Cacerts file path to javax.net.ssl.trustStore does not work in .war

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to set the path of a cacerts file to the trustStore, to do this I did:

```
String keystore = "src/main/resources/cacerts";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore);
```

I want to run the project through the STS IDE (Spring boot) it works, but when I generate the .war file and run it from the error because it does not find the path to the cacerts file, how can I set the file to work with .WAR?

I also tried to remove the System.setProperty and set the cacerts at the time of running java -jar but it also did not work:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./cacerts -jar target/uaa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .war file is a single compressed archive;  its contents are not files and cannot be directly referenced in the javax.net.ssl.trustStore property.

You can, however, use [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to copy the certificates to a new file:

```
Path keystore = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
try (InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cacerts")) {
    Files.copy(stream, keystore, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore.toString());
```

Comment: I tested the code, but this is giving error in Files.copy().
`java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\ANDRE~1.KRE\AppData\Local\Temp\5199789947340070020.tmp`
I find the error strange because every time it runs it generates a new file and the error is from FileAlteadyExists, if the file is new it should not give the error, or should it ?!

Comment: Ah, right, you need the REPLACE_EXISTING copy option, since createTempFile actually creates an empty file.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Hehe, that was it!
Thank you.